# How to restrict the maximum size of downloaded application in android

Tags: android

Hi 
I need an approach for how to restrict the size of downloaded application. 
I dont want to download a application whose size is greater than 100kb .
are there  any apis in Android which allow us to write an application that will restrict the downloaded application size? can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing whatsoever to do with Android.

If you are doing the download, use whatever means there are in your download protocol to determine the size before downloading it. For example, in HTTP, you could do a HEAD request to determine the size of the download before doing the GET request to download it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Suppose I developed an android app that downloads files over internet. What are the restrictions the user can impose on downloaded files from internet?